# Mapping a URL to a port

Tags: url

I have remote access software running on a windows server that I use to remotely connect to my clients for tech support.

For them to Access the server they have to type in my address and then append the port number to the end.

ie... http://mysite.com:8080

This is apparently extremely complicated for 90 percent of my clients.

Is there a way to map a url to a port number?

ie...http://mysite.com/connect gets translated to http://mysite.com:8080

Comment: What OS? What HTTP server? Is it possible or worthwhile setting the remote service to run on port 80 by itself?

Answer (score 1):

Since the host part of URLs define the hostname of the machine you are accessing, and the protocol (such as "http") defines how you will be talking to it - the "language" and the standard port (in HTTP's case, port 80) - you can't "map" an URL to a specific port. The only way is what you just mentioned - add the :port after the hostname.

In theory, you could do that by registering a new protocol. You could call it "scandalist://mysite.com" and define that the protocol `scandalist` is HTTP in port 8080. But that is certainly something you do not want to do - especially since you would have to change settings in your clients' computers.

Instead, you should probably rethink the way you are giving them access to the resource. Why can't you do it in port 80? If it is for security reasons, you might want to put a firewall in place or allow only connections from a VPN.

Or, if you want it to be really really simple, create a webpage somewhere (in your own host or in a free hosting) that redirects your users to that URL. Even a tinyurl would do.